# Best Settings for perfect smooth unity motion

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, updates, jitter

What I want to do is very simple. I have a camera and some objects in the scene. I need to move the camera and have a perfect smooth motion (no lag, no jitter, no spike, no hiccup). What I tried so far:

Moved camera in any kind of update function (late, fixed, prerender etc.).

To move camera, I tried two ways. 1) Increase X position of camera by deltaTime 2) Increased X position by adding a constant value in every update

Played with Application.targetFrameRate

Played with TimeManager settings, tried many many different settings.

I read ANYTHING I found on the interned related to my problem

I minimized the quality settings, everything at the lowest and Vsync is off

Important: My camera does not follow any object and no physics involved. Many developers do not recognize this problem but most of the unity game involve it and players are unconfortable.

I think the problem is that position update and screen render update are not syncronized well. There might be a solution by TimeManager and targetFrameRate.

I need experienced people's help because it seems to be calculation issue.

Comment: Post your camera's movement code please?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use lerp.
It is a function made to smoothly transition things.
Watch the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cD-mXwSCvWc) or read the [documentary](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html).
I hope this helped!